Тире или запятая перед "значит"
Если на основании изученных документов вы делаете вывод:
«Этот человек невиновен», значит, вы просто наивный человек.
нужно ли поставить тире перед "значит" вместо запятой?

Запятая отделяет придаточное от главного, она "обязательна". И без тире всё красиво.
С Вами, Наталья, я ещё не делилась "основополагающим" редакторским подходом: смотрится - не смотрится.
